# Mac: clicking between programs requires 2 clicks

Tags: macos, click

This is a simple thing but I don't see it in settings.

So, I'm in my new Mac, working in a program like Safari or Firefox.  I have a window in the background for another program, and it has a button.  I want to click that button but have to click twice, once to switch programs and once to click the button.

I want my mouse to be "hotter" than that.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 33):

Somewhat useful: you can hold <kbd>Command</kbd> and click to a non-focused window. The click will go through, however, the window will not get focus. It's useful if you have a partially covered window in the background, and you want to keep it that way, while clicking it.

BUT, if you have two windows side by side, which are not covered, it is UTTERLY frustrating that you have to click TWICE every time you want interact with them interchangeably. It would be really nice if there was an option to disable this "feature"...

Comment: I made a simple Hammerspoon script to mimic the Windows behavior. I suspect it could be done with Karabiner as well. Both are free and open-source tools. My script isn't thoroughly tested, so I'm not eager to share it just yet.

Comment: @hawk what was the approach you used in Hammerspoon to achieve this? Any chance of you sharing the code? I'm about to write one for this myself...

Answer (score 15):

This is called `click-through`, and guidelines for its usage are covered in [Apple's Human Interface Guidelines.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-TPXREF20) By default, all Cocoa controls support click-through and the feature must be turned off by the software developer. Some reasons to turn it off are covered in the Guidelines:

> Avoid providing click-through for an item or action whose result might be dangerous or undesirable. Specifically, avoid enabling click-through for an item that:
>
> - Performs a potentially harmful action that users can’t cancel (for example, the Delete button in Mail)
> - Performs an action that is difficult or impossible to cancel (such as the Send button in Mail)
> - Dismisses a dialog without telling the user what action was taken (for example, the Save button in a Save dialog that overwrites an existing file and automatically dismisses the dialog)
> - Removes the user from the current context (for example, selecting a new item in a Finder column that changes the target of the Finder window)

To answer the actual question: No. There is no global setting for this. While it could be possible for an individual application to implement settings for itself, it's not something that I've seen.

**Edit**: To answer the other part of the question, `is there any way to do this?`, the answer is sort of. If you search for `Mac focus follows mouse` or `Mac sloppy focus`, you'll find some utilities such as [Zooom/2](http://coderage-software.com/zooom/) that focuses on each window as the mouse passes over. That is something that would annoy some people, but may work for you.

Comment: yes, zooom/2 would annoy me :)
as far as guidelines, that's annoying because those are actions I build in anyway.  I click a button and it darn sure better confirm in it's own environment the action.  Clicking on it directly just because I'm blurred should make no difference.  But Mac can never be wrong.. :)

Comment: This is one of those unfortunate decisions that apple makes around UX that have kept me away from the platform. Now that I'm forced to use a mac for work, I am unendingly frustrated by the slow speed of the interface... even after a full month of using a mac and learning the shortcuts I still move about half as fast as I do on a windows machine... its a bummer, really.

Comment: @dudewad, I'm totally agree with you. It was really frustrating when I need to focus an input with TWO clicks while my left hand was not free to press Cmd key. I think the 'active-focusing' action just take a fixed time not as fast as I clicked. I have a bunch of Auto Hotkey scripts that make me feel flying on Windows. But event after purchased some productivity software to mimic the functionality of that Auto Hotkey scripts, I still felt like crawling on Mac. Really really want a click-throught-by-default options.

Comment: How utterly stupid. I usually have a podcast or video playing on my 2nd monitor and need to quickly pause it when I get phone calls. This two-click crap is crap!

Comment: The MacOSX userX has become highly frustrating because of this lack of consistency. I can hover over a non-focussed window and get hover-reactions from elements of that non-focussed window (like they're ready to be clicked), I can even two-finger scroll around the non-focussed window, then I click and (depending on the app) either nothing happens except to focus the already semi-attentive window OR both the window is brought to focus and the button as activated. I've even seen apps that are inconsistent within themselves (Outlook springs to mind).

Comment: I'm fullscreen with two browser windows on an ultrawide side by side and this two click nonsense is driving my insane.

Comment: I could get used to this behaviour if it didn't mean 2 clicks to pause a video on the another screen, which often registers as a double click.
(Double click of course maximising the video and hiding the rest of the work, including on other screens).

Comment: This still drives me crazy, even after a few years on a Mac?  Any good answers yet, in 2021?

Comment: clicking with touchpad does the click, but not with mouse. So I conclude there must be a setting to fix that bug

Comment: @darrick-herwehe the link to apple human interface guidelines does not show the specifics on focus and click through that you mentioned, perhaps the URLs changed.  Any chance you can find an updated link to the current guidelines?  Thanks!